# Python - Pandas - Fill/Append a Multi-Index DataFrame inside a loop

Tags: python, for-loop, append, fill, multi-index

Because I am unable to provide a first draft of code, I would rather describe it in the best possible way:

**I would like to know how can I create a MultiIndex DataFrame, then fill it inside a loop (where data discovery happens), knowing at each iteration, the Index Levels that should be assign to the Series considered.**

1. Should I create the MultiIndex Dataframe structure (Index names, Index Levels) before and how can I do it (I know both Index Names and Levels)?
2. What happens inside the loop? Am I appending a Multi Index DataFrame ? Am I filling a Multi Index DataFrame based on Levels (no need to append-just assign to Levels) ? How should it be coded ?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution goes like this:

```
filelist_unsorted=glob.glob(r"*/filen*", recursive=True)
for i, file in enumerate(filelist_unsorted):
    df=pd.read_csv(file)
    #some modifications
    df.drop(columns=['b','c'],inplace=True)
    #optional: add a new column that will serve as an index
    df['new']=round(values[i])
    if i>=1:
        df_stack = pd.concat([df_stack, df], axis=0)
        #NOTE axis=0 is vertical concatenation
    else:
        df_stack=df
pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df_stack)
#optional: set the index
df_stack.set_index(['new'], inplace=True)
```

1. I imported the single files ad DataFrame, after the concatenation I forced the new df to be a MultiIndex and at the end I set the relevant index(es).
2. the for loop concatenates and provides some manipulation (columns dropping, NaN correction, padding, etc.) if needed.